# Why is the sealed keyword not included in the list of access modifiers?

Tags: c#, language-design, access-modifiers, sealed

I think `sealed` should be included in the list of access modifiers in C# language. Can somebody tell the reason why it has been excluded?

Comment: because it relates to class inheritance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An *access modifier* defines *who* can access the method or class, and *when* (i.e.: `private`: only class members, `public`: everyone else etc). Marking a method or a class as `sealed` means that it cannot be inherited. It says nothing about *access* per se.

Properly said: you still need to add an access modifier if you use the `sealed` keyword (unless the default access modifier suits you).

Your confusion may be about that both keywords seem to be about protection levels. This is kind of true, but we don't have a notion of protection modifier. The `sealed` keyword is called the *sealed modifier*, because it modifies a class or method to be sealed off. This is like a boolean switch: a class or method is either sealed or it is not, regardless of its access modifiers.

To add to the confusion, there exist *sealed accessors*, which means that derivation of an accessor (gettor/settor) is not allowed (C# standard 10.7.5).

Answer (score 10):

It's not an access modifier, it's to do with whether a class can be inherited from or not...

Comment: a class, or a method, or a property

Answer (score 6):

Cause if you cannot derive from a class it doesn't mean you cannot access it.

Answer (score 1):

All the following valid class definitions feature `sealed` classes but they all have different levels of access, so you can see that `sealed` isn't an access modifier and hence isn't listed as one by Microsoft:

```
public sealed class MyPublicClass
{
}

internal sealed class MyInternalClass
{
}

private sealed class MyPrivateClass
{
}
```

You have to trust that Microsoft do know a thing or two about the language they created :)

Comment: Anders Hejlsberg architected the language c#, and he came from Borland ;-)